# Adding sections, separated by dates, to UITableView in Swift CoreData

Tags: uitableview, swift, core-data, sections

Can somebody tell me how to add sections with date using CoreData?

I have detailViewController which store all data from CoreDate, and AddTableViewController when we write some data.

Detail View Controller

```
import UIKit

import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, AddTableViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var detailTaskModel: Items!
var costsValues:Int!


@IBOutlet weak var sumLabel: UILabel!

// CoreData
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    fetchedResultsController = getFetchedResultsController()
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    fetchedResultsController.performFetch(nil)

    costsValues = getAccountCountSum()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController.sections![section].numberOfObjects
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: DetailTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailCell") as DetailTableViewCell
    let thisCost = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Costs

    cell.nazwaWydatkuLabel.text = thisCost.costsName
    cell.wartośćLabel.text = "\(thisCost.costsValue) zł"

    return cell
}

@IBAction func addCostButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addCostVC", sender: self)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    costsValues = getAccountCountSum()
    refreshTable()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

// CoreData Functions
func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Costs")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "costsDate", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}

func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return fetchedResultsController
}

// NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let thisCost = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Costs
    managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(thisCost)
    costsValues = getAccountCountSum()

    refreshTable()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).saveContext()
}

// Sum count in all accouts
func getAccountCountSum() -> Int {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Costs")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    var results: NSArray = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!

    var accountsSum: Int = 0
    for res in results {
        var accountCount = res.valueForKey("costsValue") as Int
        accountsSum += accountCount
    }
    self.sumLabel.text = String("\(costsValues) zł")
    return accountsSum
}

func refreshTable() {
    getAccountCountSum()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

AddTableViewController

```
    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // CoreData Access
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Costs", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    let cost = Costs(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    cost.costsName = cellThreeNoteTextField.text
    cost.costsValue = (cellOnePriceTextField.text).toInt()!
    cost.costsDate = datePicker.date

    // Saving data
    appDelegate.saveContext()

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Costs")
    var error:NSError? = nil

    var results:NSArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!

    for res in results {
        println(res)

    }
    delegate?.refreshTable()
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, you create sections by passing a key on your managed objects to the `sectionNameKeyPath` argument. The `sections` property of the fetched results controller will then break up the results into sections based on the values of that key path in the fetched objects.

You'll also need to implement `UITableView` callbacks to get it to use the sections-- for example, `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` and `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`. These are described in the `NSFetchedResultsController` documentation.